# Move all directories except one to another folder, if they exist, leave all files behind

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, case, mv

I'm trying to move some dirs from one location to another, but I need to leave one in place (all files will remain in place). I've tried several things, but nothing seems to work.
I have tested the value of DIR_COUNT and it works as expected. However, when used in a conditional or case statement, it doesn't work as expected.

**conditional**

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR_COUNT=$(find path/to/dir/*[^this_dir_stays_put] -type d -maxdepth 0 | wc -l)
echo $DIR_COUNT
if [[ $DIR_COUNT > 0 ]]
  then
    find path/to/dir/*[^this_dir_stays_put] -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec mv {} new/location \;
    echo "Moving dirs."
  else
    echo "No dirs to move."
fi
```

**case**

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR_COUNT=$(find path/to/dir/*[^this_dir_stays_put] -type d -maxdepth 0 | wc -l)
echo $DIR_COUNT
case $DIR_COUNT in
  0)
    echo "No dirs to move."
  *)
    echo "Moving dirs."
    find path/to/dir/*[^this_dir_stays_put] -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec mv {} new/location \;;;
esac
```

With both versions of the code, everything is fine provided the directories to be moved exist, but if there aren't any to move, I have problems.

**conditional**

```
$ sh script.sh
find: find path/to/dir/*[^this_dir_stays_put]: No such file or directory
0
No dirs to move.
```

**case**

```
$ sh script.sh
find: find path/to/dir/*[^this_dir_stays_put]: No such file or directory
0
Moving dirs.
find: find path/to/dir/*[^this_dir_stays_put]: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is when there's nothing in there for it to grab. It will say "No such file or directory" even when it's part of a conditional.

Comment: in response to the maxdepth comment, I think that's an issue on your side. it works fine for me and behaves differently based on the following number.

Comment: if that's something you need/want to figure out, you should ask a new question, because it's a bit off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skip the conditional and case statement.

```
find path/to/dir/*  \! -name 'this_dir_stays_put' -type d -maxdepth 0 \
   -exec mv {} new/location \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have something like this:

```
dir_a
dir_b
dir_c
dir_d
dir_e
```

You want to move all those directories except `dir_c`.

Sometimes the easiest way is to move all the directories to the new location, and then just move the one you want back. No?

Okay, if you use `Kornshell` it's pretty simple. If you use `Bash`, you need to first set the `extglob` option like this:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
```

Now, you can use the [extended globbing syntax](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) to specify directory exceptions:

```
$ mv !(dir_c) $new_location
```

The `!(dir_c)` matches all files except `dir_c`. This works in Kornshell. It works in BASH, but only if you've first set `extglob`.

Comment: That is essentially what I want to do, but there are files that shouldn't move either. Also, I can't move `dir_c` to `new/location`, because this is an update script and there's a new version of `dir_c` in `new/location`.